# JQuery draggable form builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make something similar to [this](http://www.edigitsoftware.com//formbuilder-v2/edit.php?id=5364)

At the moment, I have made a little progress.  I have made a sidebar which will list different form elements, and I have made it so these can be dragged and dropped onto what will be the form container.

So far, this is what it looks like
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2u1Lhyy/)

This is what I am trying to achieve but having difficulty with.  At the moment, I simply display elements like this

```
<li class="list-group-item draggable"><span class="fm-textbox-icon"></span>Text Box</li>
```

So it does not contain any form code.  Therefore, when I drag it onto my form container, I do not really want to use clone.  Instead, if it is a Text Box they drag over, it should create the following

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label green" for="fieldName">Field Label:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input id="fieldName" class="form-control" type="text" name="fieldName">
    </div>
</div>
```

This means I would somehow need to add some field properties to the dragged form element (label, size etc) , like what is seen in the first example I have shown.  I have looked at the code in the first example, and there is a lot of it.

Is there any way I can simplify this process?  I am essentially looking to build what is in the example, just on a way smaller scale.

Any advice in helping me achieve this is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: i think you need sortable instead of draggable https://jqueryui.com/sortable/